# Reducing the amount of data pulled in an Excel external data source query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I'm using the Excel Power Query (Get & Transform) to pull data from an external database.   Once I drill down and filter out the tables to the stuff I actually care about, it's roughly a hundred thousand records and maybe a half dozen fields for each.  The total amount of data (i.e. if you save the workbook once the data is downloaded..) is on the order of 30MB.

However, if I look at the amount of network bandwidth used to actually do the download, it's at least an order of magnitude larger than this, which is both hard on the network and (more importantly!) takes forever.  I'm led to conclude that it's downloading some larger block (record?  table?) than I want, but I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to actually limit this down to the stuff I want.

Comment: This seems way too localized to be answered by any of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PQ has internal, obscure logic they call "Query Folding" which attempts to push as much of the logic as possible up to your source server.  The extent of this depends on your database type (e.g. it typically sends more for SQL Server, less for ODBC) and your query design.

You probably cant easily change your database type, so what you can try is moving the filter steps as far up the step list as possible. Once it strikes a step that it can't send to the database (e.g. Split Column), the rest of the steps will be run on your Excel machine.

Also try the **Fast Load** option on your query and the **Privacy / Fast Combine / Ignore the Privacy Levels ...** setting on your workbook, if those are appropriate.